# Issue with Semantic ui react calendar

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I've defined the following component to be rendered using JSX:

```js
const TestingDate = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <DateInput
        clearable
        clearIcon={<Icon name="remove" color="red" />}
        name="date"
        value="2 Apr 2020"
        onChange={a => handleDateChange(a)}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

However, the issue I'm having is that, in the `handleDataChange`, I have to keep track of the date (namely the value prop of DateInput which is imported from "semantic-ui-calendar-react", but I can't find any reasonable way of passing that to the `handleDateChange` function... I can see it's a super basic issue but I'm kind of stuck since it's my first time working with `DateInput` and the tutorial used the older style where you'd bind a callback to the `DateInput` as a prop.

If it helps, what I'd like to do is just call this line `setDate(value)` in the `handleDataChange` function. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue, can you elaborate pls. 
`onChange` of this calendar component pass you `date`, `text`, `mode`, what is missing?

Comment: when I console.log the input into the onChange I get the event logged , which is the 'event' generic object in callbacks. However, I don't see where date, text and mode are passed. Could you explain? do i just change the Onchange to  onChange={(a, date, text, mode) => handleDateChange(a, date, text, mode)}?

Comment: I've based my response based on docs, but you can ensure what params with your snippet

Comment: Where'd you find the docs about this? I was reading https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar-react?fbclid=IwAR3jcN9OJCqC1YrEzIhS2gXE_sZG0pJuisY7QFLICeef518Nfhr9MgKodjU - but I couldn't find what you're talking about.

Comment: handleChange = (event, {name, value}) => {
    if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }
  }

Comment: Yes, I saw that. The thing is I'm using the useState() function, and in that sense I'm not storing state within any "React.Component" --> I'm using functional components. Do you have any recommendations for that either?

Comment: Can you make small https://codesandbox.io/ with your simple example?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and was able to resolve it by doing the following.

```
const TestingDate = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  function handleDateChange(name, value) {

    setDate(value)

  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <DateInput
        clearable
        clearIcon={<Icon name="remove" color="red" />}
        name="date"
        value="2 Apr 2020"
        onChange={(a, {name, value}) => handleDateChange(name, value)}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I hope that helps!